# Address location data for Israel

Tags: data-request, geospatial, address

I am trying to find address location data for Israel - that is, a geospatial point dataset giving a latitude and longitude (or similar in another co-ordinate system) for each address in Israel.

I can't seem to find anything on the Israeli Open Data site, or anything on the Israel Postal Service site.

Does such a dataset exist?